# Spring Secuirty and Cas logging redirecting

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas

I have a strange problem. I make my casAuthenticationFilter with an authenticationSuccessHandler. Everything works fine. Look my code:

```
    <beans:bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter" >
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <!-- Propiedad añadida para el redireccionamiento a AMS1.1 -->       
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="http://192.168.1.32:8080/AMS1.1/"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/forbidden.xhtml" entry-point-ref="casAuthEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/parameters.xhtml" access="hasRole('SES_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('SES_USER')" />
    <custom-filter ref="casAuthenticationFilter" position="CAS_FILTER" />
    <!--<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/cas/logout"/>-->
    <custom-filter ref="casSingleSignOutFilter" after="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
  </http>
```

But here is the catch. Whenever I Log In via localhost:8080/logingpage/ redirect me to http://192.168.1.32:8080/AMS1.1/. Thats what I want. But whenever I Log in via MyIp example 192.168.1.2/logingpage/ redirect me to page I enter. Example, wheneever I enter a page 192.168.1.2:8080/somepage redirects me to 192.168.2:8080/logingpage and when loging succes redirects me to 192.168.1.2:8080/somepage and that's what I don't want I want to redirect me to http://192.168.1.32:8080/AMS1.1/. But when I use localhost instead of my current Ip Everything works fine. Am I missing something?

My local ip is 192.168.1.32.

Comment: So you always want to go to the defaultTargetUrl after login success? Would you please try to set alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl property to true for authenticationSuccessHandler? From the API doc, if it is true, defaultTargetUrl is used in all conditions.

Comment: You are a damn f***** genius man!!!!! It works. Damn I forgot that property!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler API doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), you can achieve this by setting `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` to `true`.

> If the `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` property is set to true, the `defaultTargetUrl` will be used for the destination. Any `DefaultSavedRequest` stored in the session will be removed.